# Classification of subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^2$ up to homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

In the introduction of the book "A History of Algebraic
and Differential Topology 1900-1960" Dieudonné writes:

> Ever since the concept of homeomorphism was clearly defined, the
>   "ultimate" problem in topology has been to classify topological spaces
>   "up to  homeomorphism". That this was a hopeless undertaking was very
>   soon apparent, the subspaces of the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ being an obvious example.

Can you help me and clarify this "obvious example"?

Comment: When he says "obvious example," he means that it is obvious that it is hopeless to classify subspaces of the plane.

Comment: I would say that one cannot classify even subsets of the real line. We know that there is  continuum of these up to homeomorphism (proven by Lavrentiev in 1930s if I remember it correctly).

Comment: One can obviously obtain a subset of cardinality $n$ for each natural number $n$.